# How to add column to CachedRowSet in java 7?

Tags: java, database, cachedrowset

I want to append a new column in the fashion of

```
public CachedRowSet addColumn(cachedRowSet Original,List<item> column, String columnName);
```

or

```
public CachedRowSet addColumn(cachedRowSet Original,int column,String columnName);
```

with the column value repeated if it is a primitive.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. hard to answer without knowing the context. Who is providing that CachedRowSet? They might or might not offer a way to generate a new instance. Are you using CachedRowSetImpl from the RI?

The RowSet is not really intended for that. Can you add it to the generating SQL?  `SELECT a,b,'additional' from ...`. Or you can use your CachedRowSet and generate JoinedRowSet with a FULL_JOIN with a single field result set.

Comment: Its coming from a jdbc Teradata query. I'm using the .populate(RowSet r) method to save the rowset after the statement is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in SQL, let alone CachedRowSet, without executing DDL, and CachedRowSet doesn't support that. The part about a repeating value is an elementary violation of 3NF. You probably don't want to do any of this.